# Error: "Expression must have a constant value"

Tags: c++

I don't know if it's because I don't need it int the header of the function, but when I do int ticketClass, and int ticketAmount, and put them in the array, it says that the array must have a constant value, when to me at least it seems to already have one, I'm new to arrays and don't know what I did wrong, I appreciate any help I can get.

```
void customerData(int const CUSTOMERINFO[])
{
int const CUSTOMERINFO = 2;
int ticketClass[CUSTOMERINFO];
int ticketAmount[CUSTOMERINFO];
string moreTickets;
string customerChoice;
int i = 0;
```

Comment: You are declaring `int const CUSTOMERINFO[]` in one place, then redfining it as `int const CUSTOMERINFO = 2` on the next line.

Comment: It might be `CUSTOMERINFO` isn't shadowing, maybe you're using an old compiler? Either way, `CUSTOMERINFO` the parameter probably shouldn't share the same name as the local variable (`int const CUSTOMERINFO = 2;`).

Comment: I believe you garbled the error message when you paraphrased it. For best results, copy the full error message verbatim into your question.

Comment: Make `CUSTOMERINFO` `constexpr` and change its name to something like `CustomerInfoCount`.. Furthermore upper case names should be reserved for `macros`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the error. The error is that you're declaring a new variable with the same name as the argument. [See here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GCZeClwn05H4p5Oo)

To fix this, choose a different name. From context here, perhaps `CUSTOMER_COUNT` or `CUSTOMER_LIMIT`.